# Get picture from Firebase Storage and show it to the user Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

If I have a reference for Firebase Storage saved as String, like :

`String reference = https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/something/o/bucket%2Fp%2FprofilePicture%2Fimage_picker_26.jpg?alt=media&token=something`
And this reference points to a picture, how can I get this image from Storage and show it to the user?

I was thinking something like :

```
Image.network(reference)
```

But I read on the internet that this isn't safe and I think that this isn't so easy...I should have something like : `FirebaseStorage.instance.refFromURL(url)` before calls any widget to show it.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Why is it not safe? Image.network is just a widget to display the picture

Comment: Because it is a long lived url and creates a vulnerability since it's like to create a public link in google drive.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that the problem is that the URL returned by the [`getDownloadURL()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_storage/latest/firebase_storage/Reference/getDownloadURL.html) method is a **long lived one**. This method does not offer the possibility to configure an expiration date to the download URL. It is the same with the JS Client SDK.

However, **it is possible with the Admin SDK**, see for example the [`getSignedUrl()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#getSignedUrl) method of the Node.js Admin SDK.

So you could create a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable), that you call by passing the file reference and which returns a signedURL with an expiration date you choose.

From your Flutter app, you would call this Cloud Function as explained [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/functions/usage#calling-endpoints).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the url from the storage after upload then do:

```
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
Reference ref = storage.ref().child("folder");
UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(image);
uploadTask.then((res) {
   res.ref.getDownloadURL();
});
```

To display it you can use `Image.network()`

Comment: Nono I mean, I already have the url, I want to show it to the user but I read on the internet that "Image.network(url)" it's not a safe practice because exposes the url to the internet.